# Equation problems

Tags: equations

So I am trying to insert an equation. The output seems to be correct, but I get some error messages.

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
\label{eg:homogeneity2}
 \begin{align} 
  H(C) = - \sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|} \left\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} {a_c_k} }{n}\right log \left\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} {a_c_k}}{n}\right
 \end{align}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Comments

- You can't write "double subscripts" like `a_c_k`. You have to choose either `{a_c}_k` or `a_{c_k}`. I went for the latter in my code below.
- Your `\left...\right` syntax needs to specify what kind of bracket you want. For instance, `\left(...\right)`.
- You can't have `align` inside an `equation`, so I got rid of the `align` environment, since it wasn't doing anything. (Perhaps you intended `aligned`?)
- I took the liberty of changing `\frac{big formula}{n}` to `\frac{1}{n} big formula`, which I think is better style.
- `\centering` isn't doing anything here, so I got rid of it. Equations are centred by default.

### Fixed code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eg:homogeneity2}
  H(C) = - \sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|} \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} {a_{c_k}} \right) log \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} {a_{c_k}}\right)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! And to answer your question, I thought I had to have \align... I'm a latex-noob :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing I forgot in my answer: you should write `\log` rather than `log`. `log` is typeset as `l` multiplied by `o` multiplied by `g`.

Comment: @JohanSjons -- `align` is *not* recommended for one-line equations.  many people use it for convenience, but it's bad. some discussion appears in this question: [Spacing between equation and text inconsistent due to large equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106011/579)

Comment: @JohnWickerson Thank you so much, noticed that in the original equation, but did not know the difference! I have another question (though feeling like an idiot). When trying almost the same thing, I get some error messages:

\begin{equation}
\label{eg:homogeneity1}
  H(C|K) = - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} \sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|}  \left(\frac{a_{c_k}}{n}\right) \log \left(\frac{a_{c_k}}{\sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|} {a_{c_k}}\right)}
\end{equation}

Comment: @JohanSjons You have some mismatched braces in your formula. I suggest deleting your entire formula, so your document compiles without errors, and then gradually re-building your formula, operation by operation, taking care to match each opening `{` with a closing `}`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson
Yeah! Thanks for being pedagogical, it worked! :)

\begin{equation}
\label{eg:homogeneity1}
  H(C|K) = - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{|K|} \sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|}  \left(\frac{a_{ck}}{n}\right) \log \left(\frac{a_{ck}}{\sum\limits_{c=1}^{|C|}a_{ck}}\right)
\end{equation}